# before hook before all test cases in Mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a "before" hook that I want to run before all test cases(files), the ideal situation would be run it once and only once no matter how many test cases and which test case I run.

Now what I do is putting that "before" hook in a separate file, and do "require("../beforeAll.js")"  in the beginning of every test file,

```
//beforeAll.js
before('description', function(done) {
    //do something
    done()
}


//all test files
require('../beforeAll.js')
//test 
//......
```

which I think will run the "before" hook every time a test file runs, but I don't know better way to do it. However, when I run all the test cases, the "before" hook actually runs only once.

So my question are, why the "before" hook runs only once? What is the best way to do it in this scenario(only run once)?

Answer (score 22):

According to **[MochaJS's documentation on hooks](https://mochajs.org/#hooks)**:

`before(function() {})` runs before *all* tests in the block.
`beforeEach(function() {})` runs before *each* test in the block.

If you want to run a singular function at the start of your tests, use `before()`.
If you want to run a function before each of your tests, use `beforeEach()`.

When you make use of `require()`, you are essentially 'including' that logic in the current test, as though you are copy-pasting the required file. Considering you make use of `before()`, it runs in the first test. When it comes time to the second test, it sees that `before()` has already executed, so it does not get executed again.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, so if I want it run before each test file, I should make the required file a beforeEach? Is there a better way to do it instead of putting require in every file?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to do it before each test, you'd make it a `beforeEach()` in the required file. **Personally** if I was using a `beforeEach()` instead of a `before()`, I would have it in each of the test files. That does lead to duplicate code, but it emphasises that the `beforeEach()` is unique to that set of tests. Either way works fine, and the choice of where you store the code is up to you. Just remember that a `require()` is much like a PHP `include()`; it simply essentially copies the contents from file A into file B :)

Comment: Oh, I think beforeEach() will run before each test CASE, but not before each test FILE, so is there any way to do before each file?

Comment: That's the general idea of `beforeEach()`; it runs before each test case. Why would you want to do it before each file? Files should be split up to individual test cases... If you want to include code before each **file**, it would just be included with a regular `require()`.

Comment: There is some situation needs me to run a before hook before each file... If I do require(), if I require a before() hook, it will still only run once right?

Comment: Yes; before only happens once.

Comment: This is not quite right, as OP assumes that each file is one test case.

In reality, each file would contain a `describe()` call which defines a **suite**. Inside the callback of the describe, you define each **test case** by calling `it()`. `before()` is a hook that runs once before all tests *in the suite*. `beforeEach()` is a hook that runs *before each test in the suite*. If you want to run code before all files you should use `--require` which is ijse's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the mocha -r(--require) argument.